# Contact page if it just includes an email?

Tags: contact-us

My contact page would only have an email address. One email address, not multiple. No social media, phone numbers, location map, etc. So instead of having a contact page, I just have the business email in the navbar. However, I've been thinking that it looks unprofessional to do that. But on the other hand, having such a small contact page seems silly. And providing an email address always has seemed more convenient to me than having a contact forum.

So my question is whether or not it makes sense to have a contact page if it would only have an email address.

Comment: What's the rest of the site? Is it mostly a marketing site, or an intensive function web application? Is the contact part of a sales funnel? Or is having customers contact you a drain on support resources?

Comment: @MikeM The site is a web app that poker players use to study. The contact page isn't part of the sales funnel, it's for feedback and support. I want people to contact me as much as possible.

Comment: What about placing the email address in the footer?

Comment: @Levano I'd like to feature it more prominently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a person who used to work in technical support for a number of years, I would have a contact page, because:

- you can provide additional information (e.g., expected response times, working hours, timezone)
- guide users in helping you help them (e.g., "to report a problem, tell us about your OS version and language settings, so we can provide a faster and more specific answer")
- you can nudge them towards a FAQ or a wiki, so they can resolve their question without asking it at all

In other words, the purpose of the `contact` page is not to merely tell them your email address, it is to help them solve a problem with minimal effort.

You say you want them to contact you as often as possible, but is that really what you want? If you end up with an inbox full of "nothing works!!!11", you will have to contact them individually and ask them to be more specific, provide screenshots, tell a few words about their environment, etc. This can be prevented with a few basic profilactic measures.

Of course, this all depends on the exact nature of your business.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. In my case, my startup is at an early stage and I want to talk to users as much as possible, but I think that you are still correct in saying that there is room for additional information. I eventually decided to include information about what sort of feedback I am looking for and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing an email address you can use a contact form, with this you don't need to put any email address and your contact page will look more professional.

There are some free contact form builders very easy to use and implement like [123formbuilder.com](https://www.123formbuilder.com/html-contact-form/)
[image]

Comment: I'd prefer to have an email address instead of a contact form.

Comment: Maybe that's just me, but companies that spend any effort to prevent people from writing a regular e-mail - e.g. by hiding their e-mail address and just providing web-based contact forms - appear very much as *unprofessional* to me.